# Unable to sendKeys to a page

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to log in to `https://support.sentinelone.com/` through selenium. Somehow I'm unable to enter my credentials. Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/chromedriver");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://support.sentinelone.com/hc/en-us/restricted?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.sentinelone.com%2Fhc%2Fen-us");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("descendant::*[@class='credentials']/descendant::input[1]")))
                .sendKeys("myUser@user.com");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#user_password")).sendKeys("myPassword");
        driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in-submit-button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        List<WebElement> folders = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".blocks-item a"));
        System.out.println(folders.size());
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".blocks-item:nth-child(1) a")).getAttribute("href");
    }
```

I get the error as

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:
> Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located
> by By.xpath: descendant::*[@class='credentials']/descendant::input[1]
> (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) Build info:
> version: '4.1.0', revision: '87802e897b' System info: host:
> 'rkeerthi-mba', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:8ff:bcdc:1025:e4b1%en0', os.name: 'Mac
> OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '16.0.2'
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
> {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
> 97.0.4692.99, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 97.0.4692.71 (adefa7837d02a..., userDataDir: /var/folders/6h/hr_vvn9j0sl...},
> goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52226},
> javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false,
> pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy:
> Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:52226/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion:
> 97.0.4692.99, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000},
> unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify,
> webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true,
> webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID:
> 2f312b7acb65d1e79b013c4f4e05a6db  at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:138)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:231)
> at SentinalOneCrawler.main(SentinalOneCrawler.java:24)

Not sure of where I'm going wrong. Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: Get rid of the `Thread.sleep()`. 99.99% of the cases can be resolved with correct `ExpectedConditions` and/or `webdriver.manage().timeouts()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locators are correct, but the Creds input boxes are in an iframe.

So first switch to an iframe with the below XPath:

```
//iframe[@frameborder]
```

and then you would be able to access the element.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@frameborder]")));
```

and once you are switched to the frame, then use this line:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("descendant::*[@class='credentials']/descendant::input[1]")))
            .sendKeys("myUser@user.com");
```

also, once you are done with iframe you should switch back to the `defaultContent`

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
  driver.switchTo().window(s.get(index));    //here the index means the browser order or count
Login login = new Login(this.driver);
```

ArrayList s = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(s.get(index));    //here the index means the browser order or count

Use the above code snippet for tranferring driver control from one tab to another means moving.
Once if you done with tranferring to another tab. The Driver control will be still at the previous tab only . to get that driver to the current page we need to initialize the browser with the current driver (i.e this.driver). Below is an example for that.we need to re-initialize the objects with the current 'this.driver'  .

```
Login login = new Login(this.driver);
```

this is applicable whenever we get false browser errors